# Can I do a dynamic filter on various columns based on another one's value in spark 2?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have to do a project in Spark 2 and I was wondering if I can (and how to) filter based on a dynamic selection.

Currently my Dataframe looks like that (there is several more columns in my code, not just `age` and `colors`):

| filters (as tuple array) | color | age | target_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `[(age,5)(color,Blue)]` | Pink | 5 | 25 |
| `[(age,5)(color,Blue)]` | Blue | 5 | 27 |
| `[(age,5)]` | Pink | 5 | 30 |
| `[(color,Pink)]` | Pink | 12 | 28 |

And, for this example, I want the following output:

| filters (as tuple array) | color | age | target_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `[(age,5)(color,Blue)]` | Blue | 5 | 27 |
| `[(age,5)]` | Pink | 5 | 30 |
| `[(color,Pink)]` | Pink | 12 | 28 |

I tried with the [forall function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.forall.html) but it is only available in spark 3.

The filters columns contains an array of key-value pairs where the value have to be checked for equality among the column with the key name. So I have to filter on a non deterministic number of rows with non deterministic value.

Can I do this kind of dynamic filtering with Spark 2 or is it impossible by design to select a column based on another column value for each line?

Comment: all you need is a simple for loop (with column name and value as Map and iterate ) and add filter logic on existing dataframe /dataset

Comment: you can create a rank function and basedon tuple and order by desc and select rank=1